# Cannot reach timedelta64 Object in xArray in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-xarray, timedelta

I have some xArrays with time info and want to calculate the range:

```
data[0].time.max() - data[0].time.min()
```

which returns a xarray.DataArray with one element: `array(14393250000000, dtype='timedelta64[ns]')`

However if I want to compare it to a different timedelta e.g.

```
(data[0].time.max() - data[0].time.min()) > datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

I get
`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'`

I tried extracting the object out of the array like so:

```
(data[0].time.max() - data[0].time.min()).item() > datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

Same result.

I tried converting it to a datetime.timedelta object like so:

```
#alternative 1
time_diff = np.array([data[0].time.max() - data[0].time.min()], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')[0]

#alternative 2
time_diff = np.array([data[0].time.max() - data[0].time.min()])[0]

time_diff_dt = datetime.timedelta(microseconds=time_diff / 1000)
time_diff_dt > datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

Both alternatives return `ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue here is that `xarray` gives you a `np.timedelta64` which you are trying to compare with a `datetime.timedelta` object. So you will need to convert one to the other to make the comparison.

Further, your `np.timedelta64` has `ns` precision, whereas Python's `datetime` only goes down to microsecond precision. This is why the `.item()` (which usually should convert `np.timedelta64` to `datetime.timedelta`) is not behaving as you desire.

To resolve this, you can try converting to microseconds first:

```
diff = data[0].time.max() - data[0].time.min()  # This has type timedelta64[ns]
diff = diff.astype('timedelta64[us]')  # Convert to microsecond precision
diff = diff.item()  # Convert to Python datetime.timedelta
diff > datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)  # Now we can compare like objects
```

Alternatively, compare vs `np.timedelta64(1, 'm')` instead of `datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me after some minor issues: 'diff.item()' seems to break it, it's an int afterwards and when you compare it with 'np.timdelta64(1, 'm')' the result is always True no matter what the timedelta is. However 'np.timedelta64' is the function I needed and I can compare the outcome of the difference directly to it without any conversion.

Comment: `.item()` should work so long as you convert to `timedelta64[us]` (or `s` or any precision courser than `ns`) first. Anyways glad you fixed your issue!